# How would this code segment look as pseudo-code?

Tags: for-loop, iteration, pseudocode

I have this code:

```
for(iteration<string> it=name_list.iterator();it.hasNext();)
```

What would be a suitable pseudo-code representation for the above code?

Answer (score 2):

Since pseudo-code is meant to be more human-readable, I'd simply opt for something like:

```
for each name in name_list:
    do something with name
```

You shouldn't have any need to put implementation details like iterators in your pseudo-code, rather you should simply specify *intent.* And I find the Python style of coding suits this sort of thing perfectly.

You should also use more descriptive names than `it`. I'm assuming that's for iterator but it gives absolutely *no* indication as to what the variable is. This is something you should aim for not just in pseudo-code but in real code as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make real code into pseudocode is to screw it up. :-) mwahahaha!

That could turn into

for each iteration of name_list.iterator as it

It could turn into hundreds of others too!

Answer (score 0):

"For each item in name_list" at least that's probably the intention.  This code on its own is just an infinite loop though because it never moves the iterator